# Validating TinyMCE HTML code using W3C

Tags: html, validation, standards

I am trying to validate a tinymce generated HTML code but it appears W3C only accept url or files as an input. Any suggestion how do I validate tinymce code?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? Also, the W3C validator definitely allows you to paste in HTML. Look for the 'Validate by Direct Input' tab.

Comment: I am trying to validate user input HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to implement the validation into your application, use your own validator, for example [tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.tidy.php).

This should be much faster  than sending data across the world, and easier too, because you dont have to parse the response of the w3c-validator.